# C# Errors - File wont compile

Tags: c#

I have a code that I'm meant to compile into a .DLL file (it's for the game Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3). However, it wont compile. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
using MapEdit;
using Addon;
using System;

namespace mp_terminal_cls
{
    public class mp_terminal_cls : MapEdit
    {
        public mp_terminal_cls()
        {
        }

        createfloor(new Vector(2263f,4406f,286f),new Vector(2958f,4147f,286f));

        public override void OnMapChange()
        {
            base.OnMapChange();
        }
    }
}
```

I get 7 errors, the problem is the original code was exactly the same. I only added 2 new lines of code. Here is the errors:

[image]

Sorry I'm quite new to C# I only have about 2 months experience with VB.

Comment: What is `createfloor(new Vector(2263f,4406f,286f),new Vector(2958f,4147f,286f));` doing at class scope?

Comment: @StuartLC I have no idea sorry...As I say I only know basic VB. C# looks like gibberish to me. The plugin I originally downloaded doesn't save the "Coordinates" correctly so I'm now having to figure out how to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

1) Move the call to `createfloor` either into the constructor's body *or* `OnMapChange`'s body (from your code, we can't tell which one you need):

```
public mp_terminal_cls()
{
    createfloor(new Vector(2263f,4406f,286f),new Vector(2958f,4147f,286f));
}
```

or

```
public override void OnMapChange()
{
    createfloor(new Vector(2263f,4406f,286f),new Vector(2958f,4147f,286f));
    base.OnMapChange();
}
```

2) The base class `MapEdit` doesn't seem to have a `OnMapChanged` method.

As a side-note, your classes and namespaces should have distinct names, to avoid ambiguity issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are essentially two errors

1. MapEdit is a namespace but is used as a type usually means that you
   have a class called MapEdit inside a namespace called MapEdit. 
   Refer to it as MapEdit.MapEdit.
2. The rest are caused by the call to CreateFloor not being inside a 
   function.  I assume that it should exist inside the constructor so move it inside